# Where do Firefox and Chrome get their list of malware & phishing sites from?

Tags: browser, phishing

When you click on a hyperlink, Firefox and Chrome both check it against a list to see if the domain has been reported as a phishing site or a site containing malware.  Where does that list come from?  Do Firefox and Chrome (and maybe others) use the same list?  Who manages it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome use Google's Safe Browsing utility, which is managed by Google, as the name implies. They have a transparency report with statistics viewable at: http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/

Comment: Is there any verifiable documentation about whether or not Google stores data about all the systems that access these Google servers?  Google claims "approximately 1 billion people" access these servers.  A simple internet search reveals lawsuits against Google for alleged data collection transgressions.